# Scroll horizontally an iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe that I want to scroll horizontally and vertically with some parameters. It seems that I can scroll the page vertically without problems, but I can't scroll it horizontally ...

Here are some code samples :

HTML :

```
<iframe id="html-region" src="some local url" style="width:1000px;height:1000px;overflow:scroll" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Javascript / jQuery :

```
// None worked
$('iframe').get(0).contentWindow.scroll(200, 0);
$('iframe').get(0).contentWindow.scrollTo(200, 0);
$('iframe').get(0).window.document.body.scrollLeft += 200;
$('iframe').scrollLeft(200);
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were almost there:

```
$("#html-region").contents().find("body").scrollLeft(200);
```

a few things to keep in mind:

- Cross-Origin: you can only access iframe's content html if its located in the same origin as the page that hosts the iframe: have a look <kbd>**[Here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy)**</kbd>

   - since your url is 'some local url' there shouldnt be any problem.
- you need to wait for the iframe's contents to fully load, before you can scroll it. i usually just wait till the whole window's content is fully loaded with a `$(window).load(function(){` block.
- instead of getting a list of all the iframes and choosing the first one in the list, better address your iframe by it's id. you dont know what happens in the future, you might add another iframe before this one and you might be forced to change your code. better avoid that.

with all that being said, here is a working example:

```
//block that will be executed once the iframe's content is fully loaded
$(window).load(function(){
    //get the body element inside of the iframe
    var $myFrameContent = $("#html-region").contents().find("body");
    //adjust the scrollLeft/Top
    $myFrameContent.scrollTop(200);
    $myFrameContent.scrollLeft(50);
});
```

and here is a <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/6thKV/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer ! Sadly, it seems it does not work for me. When I set the scrollTop value directly from the console, it works, but the scrollLeft does not. Also, I can't scroll in your Fiddle ? If it can be of any help, I'm using Chrome 37 (dev channel).

Comment: hmm... well i am using chrome 35 normal, the fiddle does not have scroll bars because in order to access its contents without cross-origin restrictions, i have loaded a jsfiddle inside and it removed the scroll bars. you can however, scroll using the middle mouse button just click anywhere and drag. regarding the ScrollLeft not working, i encountered this issue when i have tried to scroll the iframe contents directly and not the `body` element inside it, are you sure you applied scrollLeft to the body element?

Comment: Yes it was that ! I was trying to scroll the iframe and it wasn't working, but scrolling the body does work. Thank you very much !